# Impact of loss of old passport on Australian Immigration process

Tags: australia, regulations

I have lost a passport that I had in the early 90s. I travelled to the US and China on it with my parents. Unfortunately I lost it sometime over the next decade as my next international travel was in 2007. SInce then I have had two passports and have travelled to different countries. I am currently in the process of having my Australian Permanent Residency/Immigration application processed. Can anyone advise whether not possesing that old passport will have an impact on the success or failure of my application?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27014/keeping-old-passports French citizens would typically be unable to present *any* old passport. Many people would also simply have lost their passports. I don't know if it can be an issue but it can't be a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need it.**  I successfully applied for Australian permanent residence and later citizenship without ever having to produce any old passports.

I *was* asked for a list of all previous visits to Australia, which would have been difficult to complete without having my old stamps, but this does not appear to be an issue for you.  Even if it was, I doubt they would care about the exact dates for a trip that ended 20 years ago (IIRC, most of the form questions were about the previous 10 years).